# Mail body data is flowing outside the div while position is relative

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have created an html page ContentPage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>Content Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ContentPage.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="containerDiv" style="position:absolute">

            <div id="headerDiv" style="position:relative">
                <img id="mailimage" src="mailView-topImage.png" alt="mailView-topImage.png"/>
                <input id="inputbutton" type="button" value="Reply"/>
            </div>

            <div class="tabular" style="position:relative">

                <div>
                     <div class="tabular-row">
                        <div class="tabular-cell">From:</div>
                        <div class="tabular-cell values"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tabular-row">
                        <div class="tabular-cell">Date:</div>
                        <div class="tabular-cell values"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tabular-row">
                        <div class="tabular-cell">Subject:</div>
                        <div class="tabular-cell values"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tabular-row">
                        <div class="tabular-cell">Attachment:</div>
                        <div class="tabular-cell values">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div id="messageBodyParent" style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%">
                    <div id="messageBody">


                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                dddddd



                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

with following css ContentPage.css

```
body
{
    padding-bottom: .3em;
    padding-left: .3em;
    padding-top: .3em;
    padding-right: .3em;
    margin: .3em;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#containerDiv
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#mailimage
{
    float: left;
}

#inputbutton
{
    background-color: white;
    height: 19px;
    color: green;
    font-size: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 1em;
    float: right;
}

#messageBody
{
    position:relative;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    padding-left: .5em;
    width:90%;
    padding-right: .5em;
    height:60%;
    margin-right: 1em;
    border: grey 3px solid;
}

.tabular
{
    display: table;

}

.tabular-row
{
    display: table-row;
}

.tabular-cell
{
    display: table-cell;
}

.values
{
    padding-left: 3em;
}
```

I have created a "containerDiv" div (It contains all other div and work as complete body container).

Inside which there are "headerDiv" div (It is used to show image and reply button) , "tabular" div (It is used to show the mail headers) , "messageBodyParent" div (It is used as parent of "messageBody" div)
and  messageBody description: To show my data in "messageBody" div (It is mail body container).

I have position "messageBodyParent" as 'relative' while "messageBody" is positioned as 'absolute'.

But when I resize the window some portion of div is not visible, as the "messageBodyParent" is relative it should adjust according to window size.

Requirement : - Data should not overflow in body container (messageBody div).And It should be shown with scroll when we will minimize the page.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Changed several styles which I'm guessing the one you want for the display.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Content Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ContentPage.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="containerDiv" style="position: absolute;">

            <div id="headerDiv" style="position:relative">
                <img id="mailimage" src="mailView-topImage.png" alt="mailView-topImage.png"/>
                <input id="inputbutton" type="button" value="Reply"/>
            </div>

            <div class="tabular" style="position:relative">
                <div>
                     <div class="tabular-row">
                        <div class="tabular-cell">From:</div>
                        <div class="tabular-cell values"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tabular-row">
                        <div class="tabular-cell">Date:</div>
                        <div class="tabular-cell values"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tabular-row">
                        <div class="tabular-cell">Subject:</div>
                        <div class="tabular-cell values"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="tabular-row">
                        <div class="tabular-cell">Attachment:</div>
                        <div class="tabular-cell values">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div id="messageBodyParent" style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                    <div id="messageBody">
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
                                dddddd
                    </div>
                </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

div
{
    overflow: hidden;
}

#containerDiv
{
    left: .6em;
    top: .6em;
    right: .6em;
    bottom: .6em;
}

#mailimage
{
    float: left;
}

#inputbutton
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0em;
    background-color: white;
    height: 19px;
    color: green;
    font-size: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#messageBody
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0em;
    top: 1em;
    right: 0em;
    bottom: 5.4em;
    text-align: justify;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding-left: .5em;
    padding-right: .5em;
    border: grey 3px solid;
}

.tabular
{
    display: table;

}

.tabular-row
{
    display: table-row;
}

.tabular-cell
{
    display: table-cell;
}

.values
{
    padding-left: 3em;
}
```